# Country data archiving script using Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've just created a script in Google Spreadsheet in order to archive some things. I have data from four countries.  If something is marked done, then that line could be archived into that country's archive.

My code is pretty ugly. Is there a clearer way to do this?

```
function CroatianArchive() 
{  
  var source_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('original');
  var target_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('croatian_backup');
  var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();
  var source_range = source_sheet.getDataRange();
  var target_range = target_sheet.getDataRange();  
  var rowsToBeDeleted = [];

  var i = 2;
  while (i <= lastRow) {
  if (source_sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue() == "CRO" && source_sheet.getRange("M"+i).getValue() == "DONE" ) {
    var office = source_sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue();
    var title = source_sheet.getRange("B"+i).getValue();
    var imdbId = source_sheet.getRange("C"+i).getValue();
    var channel = source_sheet.getRange("D"+i).getValue();
    var type = source_sheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
    var added = source_sheet.getRange("F"+i).getValue();
    var deadline = source_sheet.getRange("G"+i).getValue();
    var airing = source_sheet.getRange("H"+i).getValue();
    var link = source_sheet.getRange("I"+i).getValue();
    var picture = source_sheet.getRange("J"+i).getValue();
    var comment = source_sheet.getRange("K"+i).getValue();
    var portId = source_sheet.getRange("L"+i).getValue();
    var status = source_sheet.getRange("M"+i).getValue();
    var data = [office,title,imdbId,channel,type,added,deadline,airing,link,picture,comment,portId,status];
    target_sheet.appendRow(data);    
    rowsToBeDeleted.push(i);
    i++;
    } else {
      i++;
      }
    }  
    rowsToBeDeleted.reverse();
    for (var j = 0; j < rowsToBeDeleted.length; j++) 
    {
        source_sheet.deleteRow(rowsToBeDeleted[j]);
    }   
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Archivation finished.', 'Status');
  }
function SerbianArchive() 
{  
  var source_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('original');
  var target_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('serbian_backup');
  var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();
  var source_range = source_sheet.getDataRange();
  var target_range = target_sheet.getDataRange();  
  var rowsToBeDeleted = [];

  var i = 2;
  while (i <= lastRow) {
  if (source_sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue() == "SER" && source_sheet.getRange("M"+i).getValue() == "DONE" ) {
    var office = source_sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue();
    var title = source_sheet.getRange("B"+i).getValue();
    var imdbId = source_sheet.getRange("C"+i).getValue();
    var channel = source_sheet.getRange("D"+i).getValue();
    var type = source_sheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
    var added = source_sheet.getRange("F"+i).getValue();
    var deadline = source_sheet.getRange("G"+i).getValue();
    var airing = source_sheet.getRange("H"+i).getValue();
    var link = source_sheet.getRange("I"+i).getValue();
    var picture = source_sheet.getRange("J"+i).getValue();
    var comment = source_sheet.getRange("K"+i).getValue();
    var portId = source_sheet.getRange("L"+i).getValue();
    var status = source_sheet.getRange("M"+i).getValue();
    var data = [office,title,imdbId,channel,type,added,deadline,airing,link,picture,comment,portId,status];
    target_sheet.appendRow(data);    
    rowsToBeDeleted.push(i);
    i++;
    } else {
      i++;
      }
    }  
    rowsToBeDeleted.reverse();
    for (var j = 0; j < rowsToBeDeleted.length; j++) 
    {
        source_sheet.deleteRow(rowsToBeDeleted[j]);
    }   
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Archivation finished.', 'Status');
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of repeated code when creating the `data` array. Note that the names of each cell value are ultimately irrelevant. That part could also be expressed as:

```
var columns = ["A" // office
              ,"B" // title
              ,"C" // imdbId
              ,"D" // channel
              ,"E" // type
              ,"F" // added
              ,"G" // deadline
              ,"H" // airing
              ,"I" // link
              ,"J" // picture
              ,"K" // comment
              ,"L" // portId
              ,"M" // status
              ];
var data = columns.map(function (col) {
  return source_sheet.getRange(col + i).getValue();
});
```

Less redundant code, same level of documentation.

Code like

```
if (...) {
  ...;
  i++;
} else {
  i++;
}
```

is usually better written as:

```
if (...) {
  ...;
}
i++;
```

However, we now have

```
var i = 2;
while (i <= lastRow) {
  ...;
  i++;
}
```

which is a more complicated formulation of

```
for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  ...;
}
```

Similarly,

```
rowsToBeDeleted.reverse();
for (var j = 0; j < rowsToBeDeleted.length; j++) 
{
    source_sheet.deleteRow(rowsToBeDeleted[j]);
}
```

is the same as:

```
for (var i = rowsToBeDeleted.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  source_sheet.deleteRow(rowsToBeDeleted[i]);
}
```

If I see that correctly, your two function only differ in the strings `croatian_backup` vs. `serbian_backup` and `CRO` vs. `SER`. Instead of copy-pasting that code, take those strings from the function parameters. Now we have a general `archive` function:

```
function archive(outputSheet, languageCode) { ... }
```

If you need two seperate funtions that don't take any arguments, we can use the [*currying* technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (also known as partial application) to pre-fill the arguments:

```
function CroatianArchive() {
  return archive("croatian_backup", "CRO");
}
```

Some of your names use underscores, other capitalization to separate words:

```
source_range
lastRow
```

You should settle for one style – Javascript tends to prefer capitalization rather than underscores.

Comment: I wouldn't call it currying or partial application since there's nothing partial about it. Your example doesn't curry a function; it just calls one.

Comment: @Flambino You are technically correct, and I lied in my answer in order to pin a name on this specialization technique. I picked “*currying*” because I couldn't think of anything better, and because it is effectively a similar abstraction. Because JavaScript has side effects, I transformed `archive :: (String, String) → ()` into `CroatianArchive :: () → ()`, which can be seen as the end step of `CroatianArchive' :: String → String → () → ()`. The word “*priming*” might be a better alternative (which is what [Perl6 calls this](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S06.html#Priming), and which I emulated).

Comment: Priming's a good name for it. To be honest, I never thought of what one might call it; I'd probably just call it a "shortcut" or something :) But it's funny, I reasoned the same as you when I wrote my comment. If currying means reducing the arity of a function, then reducing the arity to zero would be "currying". But then every function invocation would fall in that category and it'd sorta lose its meaning